# How to detect acess file in host

Tags: php

I have some file has upload to server. I want detect some this  file to be access or not. if it access will write to access log.  I has use

> $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

but it only detect access site, not file. 
My question: How to detect file access.

Comment: Can you give an example HTTP URL, corresponding file name, and what kind of log message you want?

Comment: Write an access wrapper script (e.g. via `RewriteRule` even), and look for `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the file has been accessed over HTTP, and not excluded from logging somehow, then the access will be recorded in the access.log without need for any intervention from PHP.

So… do nothing.

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that the OP would like to know if the PHP script itself opens and reads the contents of a file...